# Is there a way to use a tuple element which is an array, as a set inside a "sum" of a "forall" loop?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a short version of my code to not make the explanation too complicated. Basically the N_B is just a set of nodes that are connected to each other like node 1 connected to node 2 and 3; node 4 connected to node 5, 6 and 7. I need to make a multiplication between the first node in the tuple and the summation of all the secondary nodes for each time "t". The nodes are collected in "I". But it gives the "cannot extract expression"  error. I know the error is related to this line sum(j in i.node2) but I don't know why or how to fix it.

```
range T=1..12;
range I=1..7;
dvar float C_all;
dvar float V[I][T];

tuple N_B_type{
    int node1;
    {int} node2;
}
{N_B_type} N_B={<1,{2,3}>,<4,{5,6,7}>};

minimize C_all;
subject to{
    
    forall(i in N_B,t in T){
    
       -V[i.node1][t]*(sum(j in i.node2)(V[j][t]))==0;
    
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since ab==0 is equivalent with a==0 or b==0 you could write

```
forall(i in N_B,t in T){
    
       -V[i.node1][t]==0 || (sum(j in i.node2)(V[j][t]))==0;
    
    }
```

If you use MIP within CPLEX you cannot write such x times y
If you move to Constraint Programming within CPLEX then you could.

The following works fine

```
using CP;
range T=1..12;
range I=1..7;
dvar int C_all;
dvar int V[I][T];

tuple N_B_type{
    int node1;
    {int} node2;
}
{N_B_type} N_B={<1,{2,3}>,<4,{5,6,7}>};

minimize C_all;
subject to{
    
    forall(i in N_B,t in T){
    
       -V[i.node1][t]*(sum(j in i.node2)(V[j][t]))==0;
    
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I tried using CP, and cplex freezes for some reason. I have to force close cplex and open again. Do you have any insight of why is this happening?

Comment: Which CPLEX version do you use ?

Comment: I use cplex 12.6

Comment: Maybe you should move to a newer version. See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/detailed-system-requirements-ibm-ilog-cplex-optimization-studio

Comment: Yeah. I changed to dvar float+ and now it doesn't freeze. Thank you.